# AWS Connect Outbound call not happening

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am new to AWS Services. I follow AWS documentation to create in-bound flow and it's working fine for me. while I am trying to outbound call from AWS Lambda but call (Destination Number was Canada Number) was not happing to the customer. Below are the code snippet and AWS Flow.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' })

const connect = new AWS.Connect();

exports.handler = async (event) => {

    var params = {
        InstanceId: "XXX", //My instance ID
        ContactFlowId: "8dc1b8e3-c8eb-XXX", // flow ID
        SourcePhoneNumber: "+1000000", // Source Number
        DestinationPhoneNumber: "+100000000" // AWS Claim phone number
    };
    console.log(params);
    connect.startOutboundVoiceContact(params, function (error, response) {
        console.log('Inside function');
        if(error) {
            console.log(error)
            callback("Error", null);
        } else
        {
            console.log('Initiated an outbound call with Contact Id ' + JSON.stringify(response.ContactId));
            callback(null, 'Success');
        }
    });
};
```

Below Image is AWS Connect flow.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUO9q.png)

I have also add Policy in AWS Lambda configuration.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oj0qd.png)

- I have try to give all permission to AWS Lambda for Outbound call
- Also try with Outbound whisper flow, Contact Inbound flow but no luck with call
- also added queueId for AWS Lambda for Outbound call

Comment: Hi @Divyang did you end up getting this to work?